# How to supply power to INA128 amplifier

Tags: power-supply, amplifier

I'm trying to amplify an EMG signal from two electrodes with a INA128. However, I'm not sure how to connect the power supplies. I'm taking the 12V from the wall and using a voltage divider to get +6V and -6V. +6V goes to pin 7, -6V goes to pin 4. What should I connect to pin 5 (Ref)? The "ground" electrode?

Also, would it be wrong to supply 12V to pin 7 and 0V to pin 4?

Thanks!

[image: INA 128]

Comment: Datasheet says?

Comment: Also, what's your EMG circuit?

Comment: Using a voltage divider as a power supply is generally a bad idea. But its not clear from your question how you're using it. Add a circuit diagram to your question so we can see ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm taking the 12V from the wall and using a voltage divider to get +6V and -6V. +6V goes to pin 7, -6V goes to pin 4.

If this means your are making a virtual ground at the midpoint between the 12 V supply's positive and negative terminals, that might work. But it would be better to buffer this 0 V reference to ensure that it's potential doesn't vary when current needs to flow in or out of the ground node.

You also need to be sure that the input signal voltages of the in-amp are always between the rails. That is, never below the negative supply voltage or above the positive supply voltage (unless explicitly allowed by the datasheet, and then usually only a few 100 mV of excursion beyond the rails is allowed).

> What should I connect to pin 5 (Ref)? The "ground" electrode?

The Ref pin is the reference for the output. You could connect it to your virtual ground.

If you're connecting this output to an ADC you would likely connect the REF pin to the ADC circuit's ground. But you'd also likely want to make some connection from your virtual ground to the ADC ground to keep all your signal voltages between the rails.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a EMG circuit it's better to make the simetrical supply. If you check the document from TI you will see that you can supply up to +-18V.

When I built this circtui I used +-10V supply. On page 18 of the document you will fin a good example of first part of EMG.

Search for RIght Leg circuit it will help you.

Ref goes to GND.

Also be carefull with GAIN use a big value!!!! In my case i used a gain of aroung 700.